# How to fix clickable jQuery row within EJS Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I am a beginner Web Developer, and I was trying to create an EJS application with a table of notional employee information. I wanted the table to show more info when a row, or employee, is selected. I tried with a basic jQuery clickable-row solution, but the url I specified (which is for testing purposes) isn't being brought up. Can you please help me?

-- index.ejs --

```
<tbody>
    <% newEmployee.forEach(function(employee) { %>
        <tr class="clickable-row" data-url="https://www.google.com/">
            <td><%= employee.name %></td>
            <td><%= employee.title %></td>
            <td><%= employee.email %></td>
        </tr>
     <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

-- scripts.ejs --

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.clickable-row').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("url");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **$(selector).on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )** insted of **click()** because row are generated dynamically.

```js
    var employee = [{ name: 'abc', title: 'pqr', email: 'a@b.c' }, { name: 'abc', title: 'pqr', email: 'a@b.c'}];

         var tbody=$('<tbody/>');
      $.each(employee,function(i,e){
          var tr = $('<tr data-url="https://www.google.com/"></tr>').addClass('clickable-row');
            tr.append('<td>'+e.name+'<td/>');
            tr.append('<td>'+e.title+'<td/>');
            tr.append('<td>'+e.email+'<td/>');
            tbody.append(tr);
        });
        $('table').append(tbody);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.clickable-row').on('click', function () {
                var url = $(this).data('url');
                window.location = url;
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border:1px solid black"></table>
```